# MDX drill intermediate level in iccube

Tags: mdx, iccube

Working with IcCube 6.8, I Have a Hierarchy called [Pole_UM_UF_PH].[Pole_UM_UF (PH)] with 4 levels as following :

- Pole
- Structure
- UM
- UF

Using MDX, I want to show only Poles and their UM (possibly the ALL-M on TOP, but not the Structure nor UF)

I tried using following MDX but it permits to drill on Structure and UF.

```
select [Measures].[Nb RUM] on 0,
non empty {[Pole_UM_UF_PH].[Pole_UM_UF (PH)].[All-M] + [Pole_UM_UF_PH].[Pole_UM_UF (PH)].[Pole] + [Pole_UM_UF_PH].[Pole_UM_UF (PH)].[UM]} on 1
from [Cube]
```

Is there a way to do that without recreating a new Hierarchy containing only Pole and UM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible without creating a new hierarchy.

Even using a [perspective](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/adv_perspectives.php) hiding the level [Structure] would mean the level [UF] is not visible anymore.